# Sealing the gap between foundation and siding supposed in small section where a water pipe enters wall through foundation

Tags: insulation

I've read other posts where it is recommended not to seal the gap between the bottom row of clapboard / siding and the foundation to ensure drainage and evaporation.  However, the extreme cold in South Carolina today caused a pex pipe that comes through the slab into an exterior wall to a toilet to freeze.  Luckily I was able to heat the wall from the inside with a hair dryer and thaw it before permanent damage, but I would like to add spray foam underneath the siding for about 3 linear feet where this pipe enters the wall. My thought is that there will still be plenty of air circulation for moisture prevention overall behind the wall.  Sound reasonable?

Toilet Supply Line Exits very corner of slab
[image: Toilet Supply Line Exits very corner of slab]

Supply enters wall at rear of notched out sillplate

[image: Supply enters wall at rear of notched out sillplate]

Image from ground up to sillplate

[image: Image from ground up to sillplate]

Added descriptive pictures on 12/26/2022.  I actually hadn't looked from the outside until after this freeze event (only had the pre-build pictures), but now that I have, it certainly looks like the expanding foam that the builder sprayed from the inside left a gap underneath where the 8 degree temps and wind the other day had some access to that pipe.  It does seem like some carefully applied exterior foam would potentially help there and if I stick a think piece of cardboard between the sheathing and the insulation behind the hardee board, I may even be able to totally maintain the airflow behind the hardee board.  but even if i filled that entire area for about 1 - 1.5 feet with foam, i assume it would be harmless.  Make sense?

Comment: Please add a picture showing your situation, that will help others to give you appropriate answers. I would not think your spray foam plan is there best course, but it really depends on what you really have going on.

Comment: How much material is between the drainage plane (air/water barrier surface) and the pipe in question?

Comment: Added pictures and description